# elementary install freezing

Tags: release-loki, system-installation

I am trying to install elementary OS as a dual boot on my new XPS and keep getting a frozen screen on the logo.

I escaped the graphical view to look into the terminal and saw a large number of what appear to be errors.

[image: Errors here]

I have now also tried installing straight Ubuntu and I am getting the same behaviour. Stalling on the welcome screen prior to any dialog screens.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

I am on a brand new Dell XPS 15 with a 220gb partition from my main windows boot drive.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so thanks to someone that knows what they are actually doing on ask Ubuntu I got my answer.

The problem is with the dell XPS specifically. You need to enter grub and add acpi_rev_override=1 after quiet splash. This worked a treat for me.

I take no credit as I didn't find the fix but I hope it helps you if you are stuck.

Here is the thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025900/16-04-install-freezing-with-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu6-stuck-for-22s/1025902#1025902