# Messed up my first install, any tips for the next try?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I have just tried to install elementary as a dual boot alongside windows 10 on my new XPS 15 and it was a bit of a train crash.

After some issues with Dell specifically, see here - [elementary install freezing](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15376/elementary-install-freezing) - I managed to get elementary to live load from the USB boot.

I then followed the install instructions and chose "something else" as the install option. I then added a root partition and a swap partition which I had freed up space for earlier on in windows 10.

All seemed ok but then when prompted to restart I clicked the restart button and everything just froze. I rebooted several times to have the same result.

So, I then tried deleting the partitions from windows. The main partition deleted fine but I could not delete the swap partition so on reboot I kept getting grub.

As a result I am doing a fresh install of windows to start from scratch.

The advice I specifically need and would appreciate help with is:

What happens if I choose 'install along side windows' rather than 'something else'?

How do I get rid of grub and the old partitions? My windows machine has just rebooted and grub again came up during one of the windows reinstall starts.

Has anyone else successfully got an XPS 15 running elementary alongside windows?

Comment: you have posted a lot of other questions. I never tried the option to install alongside windows instead of something else. but i suppose it could work. only **first you should find the cause of your initial failure with installing elementary**. it might be related to the way windows 10 shuts down (that is doesn't fully shut down) or with hardware compatibility. have you tested for some time with the live usb?

Comment: I have given up on elementary OS for now so no more questions :)

Comment: been there. but i'm back. just like democracy, Linux sucks, but once you get the taste of it...

Comment: Haha - nice analogy. I am sticking with Ubuntu for now as need stability for dev. I am sure elementary is stable once installed and running but I lack sufficient knowledge to get it there right now...as Arnie said, 'I'll be baaach'

Comment: elementary is based on  ubuntu LTS,  has the same installer and the desktop is gnome-similar, lighter than gnome and less buggy than unity.  I never had problems with installing it, I just imagine you would risk the same errors with ubuntu. Glad you didn't. What ubuntu are you using if you don't mind my curiosity.